# PHP - Format date/time

Tags: php

Suppose I got the string of date look like "01:07:13 May 07, 2011 PDT", how can I format it to the format like "2007-07-20 17:20:07" (data type - timestamp) so that I can insert it to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$date="01:07:13 May 07, 2011 PDT";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($date));
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/aP7Jlg72)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date="01:07:13 May 07, 2011 PDT";
$query = "UPDATE table SET datefield = str_to_date('$date','%M %d,%Y PDT') 
          WHERE ...."
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: imo better solution than converting it in php, clearer and less hassle... +1