# Formatting a date in PHP

Tags: php, date

This is what my current code this look:

```
<?php echo $user_join_date; ?>
```

This is what it echo's:

> 2011-04-24

I want it to echo this:

> April 4th, 2011

What is the easiest way to that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL - Format date/time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920225/php-mysql-format-date-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($user_join_date)); ?>
```

See the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)