# convert input date to mysql readable format

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MySQL - Format date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920225/php-mysql-format-date-time)

I have input field (name:day1 and varchar) to enter date in my form. It attached with a jquery calendar and picks the date in the format "D, dd M, yy" (I WANT TO PICK LIKE THIS AND CANT CHANGE FORMAT). I want to convert and save into mysql date format into table. How is this possible?

```
$insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            venue,
            day1,
            day2,
            day3,
            day4,
            day5,
            day6,
            day7,
            day8,
            day9,
            day10,
            city,
            contactperson,
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['venue']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day1']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day2']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day3']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day4']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day5']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day6']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day7']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day8']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day9']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day10']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['city']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['contactperson']) . '",
            )';
```

day 1 to day 10 are the dates want to convert...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or in the sql statement you can do that:

```
$insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(             
    venue,             
    day1,             
    day2,             
    day3, 
    (.......) )             
    values             
    ("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['venue']) . '",             
     STR_TO_DATE("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day1']) . '","%W, %d %M, %y"),             
     STR_TO_DATE("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day2']) . '","%W, %d %M, %y"),
     STR_TO_DATE("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['day1']) . '","%W, %d %M, %y"),   
     (.......) )';
```

The "%W, %d %M, %y" bit must be in the same format as the date you get from your calendar...

To check all date functions and dates format see these links:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

I hope that helps...

Comment: wow. I can't write your query in details for you. you have to look at it and change bits and pieces for it to work with your variables. you must replace $your_date_string with variable in which you store the date you get from your calendar. Also replace (date) with date field in which you want to store the date in database...

Comment: Sorry...Actually i confused. Please check i edited my question.....

Comment: Thank you its working... but year showing 2020 if i insert todays date.

Comment: are you getting year from calendar as 2-digit or 4-digit? Best send me an example date you are getting from your calendar...

Comment: if I insert "Saturday, 27 Aug, 2011", converted output getting is "2020-08-27"

Comment: change %y to %Y in my code, that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your date input:

`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['date_input']));`

As long as [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) picks up the right timestamp from your input, you should be ok. Don't forget to escape it as well.

Comment: It showing the error  Undefined index: day1 in....Escape means?

Comment: Escape means protect your inputs for harmful MySQL queries, this is something you should learn about before getting this far anyway. Google "mysql injection". As for your PHP error, you will need to show some more code.